Portal returned error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied
I need to start the browser so that other programs cannot read its files.
I run browser with group change:
sudo -g permission-yandex-browser -E yandex-browser
everything works. But when I select a file in browser, an error occurs (in the console) and the file selection is not shown:
ERROR:select_file_dialog_linux_portal.cc(719)] Portal returned error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Portal operation not allowed: Unable to open /proc/214500/root
Does anyone know how to fix this?

I had the same problem.
chrome Version 127.0.6533.119 (Official Build) (64-bit)
/etc/ubuntu-releases:   | Ubuntu 20.04 LTS   | Focal Fossa

My ~/.xsession-errors file had a lot of these errors
ERROR:select_file_dialog_linux_portal.cc(761)]
  Portal returned error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied:
    Portal operation not allowed: Unable to open /proc/.../root

I found info on the 'DBus portal' here https://flatpak.github.io/xdg-desktop-portal/docs/doc-org.freedesktop.portal.FileChooser.html
And following suggestions here https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/XDG_Desktop_Portal I installed flatpak-xdg-utils
I also upgraded 'fuse' to 'fuse3'
My resulting installs, after which chrome can save files again:
# dpkg --get-selections | grep -iE "xdg|flatpak|fuse"

exfat-fuse                 install
flatpak                    install
flatpak-xdg-utils          install
fuse                       deinstall
fuse3                      install
gir1.2-flatpak-1.0:amd64   install
gvfs-fuse                  install
ifuse                      install
libflatpak0:amd64          install
libfuse2:amd64             install
libfuse3-3:amd64           install
libsquashfuse0:amd64       install
python3-xdg                install
xdg-dbus-proxy             install
xdg-desktop-portal         install
xdg-desktop-portal-gtk     install
xdg-user-dirs              install
xdg-user-dirs-gtk          install
xdg-utils                  install

